# bootstrap open modal from another page and javascript file

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i try open modal from another page and javascript file and got only black screen

javascript file

```
    $('.myModal').on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : base_url +"/Time",
        data: "_token=HZNyRybabXWcTwp4kbeVpVsUGiuiYzFBDdiRJtZk" ,
        success: function(response) 
        {
            console.log(response);
            $('.Stime').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

home page

```
<div class="Stime"></div>


    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModals">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>
```

modal page

Time.html

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModals" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i dont know why i got only black screen

Comment: Are you sure you are getting anything back from your AJAX request or that it is not erroring for some reason?

Comment: yes no problem in my controller everything work good but modal open and close and black screen stay in home page and i refresh page for delete it

Comment: Ah - you have duplicate ids (`id = "myModal"`) - change one or the other to fix.

Comment: nothing happen i change duplicated id still error and change id to css class and still have the problem

Comment: please change your code here so we can see the changes

Comment: check code now.

Comment: Please remove 2 "class" attribute from  Launch demo modal button . and also bounded jquery ready function $( function() {  in "myModal" click function